# attempt reinstalling procps will remove i386 packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, multiarch

I'm running lubuntu 20.04. debsums tells me; it is missing a conf file from package procps.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::=--confmiss procps
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libaom0:i386* libapparmor1:i386* libasn1-8-heimdal:i386* libasound2:i386* libasyncns0:i386* libavcodec58:i386* libavutil56:i386* libblkid1:i386*
  libcairo-gobject2:i386* libcairo2:i386* libcap2:i386* libcodec2-0.9:i386* libcom-err2:i386* libdatrie1:i386* libdb5.3:i386* libdbus-1-3:i386*
  libexif12:i386* libfaudio0:i386* libflac8:i386* libfontconfig1:i386* libfreetype6:i386* libfribidi0:i386* libgcrypt20:i386* libgd3:i386*
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386* libglib2.0-0:i386* libgmp10:i386* libgnutls30:i386* libgomp1:i386* libgphoto2-6:i386* libgphoto2-port12:i386*
  libgraphite2-3:i386* libgsm1:i386* libgssapi3-heimdal:i386* libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386* libgstreamer1.0-0:i386* libharfbuzz0b:i386*
  libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386* libheimbase1-heimdal:i386* libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386* libhogweed5:i386* libhx509-5-heimdal:i386* libicu66:i386*
  libjbig0:i386* libjpeg-turbo8:i386* libjpeg8:i386* libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386* liblcms2-2:i386* libldap-2.4-2:i386* libltdl7:i386* liblz4-1:i386*
  liblzma5:i386* libmount1:i386* libmp3lame0:i386* libmpg123-0:i386* libncurses6:i386* libnettle7:i386* libnuma1:i386* libogg0:i386* libopenal1:i386*
  libopenjp2-7:i386* libopus0:i386* liborc-0.4-0:i386* libp11-kit0:i386* libpango-1.0-0:i386* libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386* libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386*
  libpcap0.8:i386* libpcre2-8-0:i386* libpcre3:i386* libpixman-1-0:i386* libpng16-16:i386* libpulse0:i386* libroken18-heimdal:i386* librsvg2-2:i386*
  libsasl2-2:i386* libsasl2-modules-db:i386* libsdl2-2.0-0:i386* libselinux1:i386* libshine3:i386* libsnappy1v5:i386* libsndfile1:i386* libsndio7.0:i386*
  libsoxr0:i386* libspeex1:i386* libsqlite3-0:i386* libstb0:i386* libswresample3:i386* libsystemd0:i386* libtasn1-6:i386* libthai0:i386* libtheora0:i386*
  libtiff5:i386* libtwolame0:i386* libusb-1.0-0:i386* libuuid1:i386* libva-drm2:i386* libva-x11-2:i386* libva2:i386* libvdpau1:i386* libvkd3d1:i386*
  libvorbis0a:i386* libvorbisenc2:i386* libvpx6:i386* libwavpack1:i386* libwayland-client0:i386* libwayland-cursor0:i386* libwayland-egl1:i386*
  libwebp6:i386* libwebpmux3:i386* libwind0-heimdal:i386* libwine:i386* libwrap0:i386* libx264-155:i386* libx265-179:i386* libxcb-render0:i386*
  libxcb-shm0:i386* libxcursor1:i386* libxi6:i386* libxkbcommon0:i386* libxml2:i386* libxpm4:i386* libxrandr2:i386* libxrender1:i386* libxvidcore4:i386*
  libzvbi0:i386* ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386* wine32:i386*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 128 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 233 kB of archives.
After this operation, 385 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

but i need them for world of goo installed with playonlinux.

Is my command for reinstalling wrong?

```
apt-cache policy procps
procps:
  Installed: 2:3.3.16-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2:3.3.16-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 2:3.3.16-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

thanks for reading with regards.

Note upgrading runs smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it on my special way.
with granted rights.

```
apt-mark manual libwine:i386 wine32:i386
```

Note do only this, if you know what you do. apt-mark is no cure-all possibility.
Changed the reinstall command a bit.

```
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::=--confmiss --reinstall install procps
```